# Why do I first have to strcpy() before strcat()?

Tags: c, c-strings

Why does this code produce runtime issues:

```
char stuff[100];
strcat(stuff,"hi ");
strcat(stuff,"there");
```

but this doesn't?

```
char stuff[100];
strcpy(stuff,"hi ");
strcat(stuff,"there");
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`strcat` will look for the null-terminator, interpret that as the end of the string, and append the new text there, overwriting the null-terminator in the process, and writing a new null-terminator at the end of the concatenation.

```
char stuff[100];  // 'stuff' is uninitialized
```

Where is the null terminator?  `stuff` is uninitialized, so it might start with NUL, or it might not have NUL anywhere within it.

In C++, you can do this:

```
char stuff[100] = {};  // 'stuff' is initialized to all zeroes
```

Now you can do strcat, because the first character of 'stuff' is the null-terminator, so it will append to the right place.

In C, you still need to initialize 'stuff', which can be done a couple of ways:

```
char stuff[100]; // not initialized
stuff[0] = '\0'; // first character is now the null terminator,
                 // so 'stuff' is effectively ""
strcpy(stuff, "hi ");  // this initializes 'stuff' if it's not already.
```

Comment: `{}` is not a valid initializer in C.

Comment: bah!  I missed the `C` tag.  Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to do `char stuff[100] = {0};` though.

Comment: I'd prefer `char stuff[100]="";` for initialization, although most cases the first assignment *is* a strcpy.

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, `stuff` contains garbage.  `strcat` requires both the destination and the source to contain proper null-terminated strings.

```
strcat(stuff, "hi ");
```

will scan `stuff` for a terminating `'\0'` character, where it will start copying `"hi "`. If it doesn't find it, it will run off the end of the array, and arbitrarily bad things can happen (i.e., the behavior is undefined).

One way to avoid the problem is like this:

```
char stuff[100];
stuff[0] = '\0';      /* ensures stuff contains a valid string */
strcat(stuff, "hi ");
strcat(stuff, "there");
```

Or you can initialize `stuff` to an empty string:

```
char stuff[100] = "";
```

which will fill all 100 bytes of `stuff` with zeros (the increased clarity is probably worth any minor performance issue).

Answer (score 2):

Because `stuff` is uninitialized before the call to `strcpy`.   After the declaration `stuff` isn't an empty string, it is uninitialized data.

`strcat` appends data to the end of a string - that is it finds the null terminator in the string and adds characters after that.  An uninitialized string isn't gauranteed to have a null terminator so `strcat` is likely to crash.

If there were to intialize `stuff` as below you could perform the strcat's:

```
char stuff[100] = "";
strcat(stuff,"hi ");
strcat(stuff,"there");
```

Comment: Answer is complete, but in the case a beginner doesn't understand: The first line added the initialization with empty string (no characters in it) - but as any string in double quotes it has a null terminating character (usually 0x00) at the end. That is the character, which the `strcat` is looking for. In another words, the initialization did this: `stuff[0] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Strcat append a string to existing string.  If the string array is empty, it is not going go find end of string (`'\0'`) and it will cause run time error.

According to Linux man page, simple strcat is implemented this way:

```
   char*
   strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
   {
       size_t dest_len = strlen(dest);
       size_t i;

       for (i = 0 ; i < n && src[i] != '\0' ; i++)
           dest[dest_len + i] = src[i];
       dest[dest_len + i] = '\0';

       return dest;
   }
```

As you can see in this implementation, `strlen(dest)` will not return correct string length unless `dest` is initialized to correct c string values.  You may get lucky to have an array with the first value of zero at `char stuff[100];` , but you should not rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I would advise against using `strcpy` or `strcat` as they can lead to some unintended problems.

Use [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) and [`strncat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat), as they help prevent buffer overflows.

Comment: [No, `strncpy()` is not a "safer" `strcpy()`](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).