# C printf changing contents of variable inside function

Tags: c, gcc

So I am writing a little function to parse paths, it looks like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int parse_path() {
    char *pathname = "this/is/a/path/hello";
    int char_index = 0;
    char current_char = pathname[char_index];
    char *buffer = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    char *current_char_str = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));

    while (current_char != '\0' && (int)current_char != 11) {
        if (char_index == 0 && current_char == '/') {
            char_index++; current_char = pathname[char_index];
            continue;
        }

        while (current_char != '/' && current_char != '\0') {
            current_char_str[0] = current_char;
            current_char_str[1] = '\0';

            buffer = (char *)realloc(buffer, (strlen(buffer) + 2) * sizeof(char));
            strcat(buffer, current_char_str);

            char_index++; current_char = pathname[char_index];
        }

        if (strlen(buffer)) {
            printf("buffer(%s)\n", buffer);
            current_char_str[0] = '\0';
            buffer[0] = '\0';
        }

        char_index++; current_char = pathname[char_index];
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    parse_path();
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, there is undefined behavior in my code, it looks like the `printf` call inside the main method is changing the `buffer` variable... as you can see, the output of this program is:

```
buffer(this)
buffer(is)
buffer(a)
buffer(path)
buffer(hello)
buffer(buffer(%s)
)
buffer(hello)
hello
```

I have looked at other posts where the same sort of problem is mentioned and people have told me to use a `static` char array etc. but that does not seem to help.
Any suggestions?

For some reason, at one time in this program the `"hello"` string from `printf` is present in my `buffer` variable.

Comment: `strcat(buffer, current_char_str);` but `buffer` has never been initialized.

Comment: `realloc` may return null, especially when `strlen(buffer)` of the uninitialized buffe is too large.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, Indeed I was wondering about the same thing `strcat(buffer, current_char_str);` and reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838933/why-do-i-first-have-to-strcpy-before-strcat)

Comment: You do `strlen(buffer)` in the first `realloc` while buffer points to uninitialized memory

Comment: `buffer = (char*) realloc(buffer, (strlen(buffer) + 2) * sizeof(char));` shouldn't include `(char*)` (no need to cast return of `malloc,calloc,realloc`) and `* sizeof(char)` (always `1`). You should not `realloc` the pointer itself, instead use a temp pointer and validate `realloc` succeeded before assigning new block to `buffer`, e.g. `void *tmp =   realloc(buffer, (strlen(buffer) + 2); if (!tmp) { perror ("realloc-tmp"); break; buffer = tmp;`. Then if `realloc` fails, you don't overwrite `buffer` with `NULL` creating a memory leak.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I did as you said and now I am getting the error string `"realloc-tmp"` inside my buffer variable ... hahah

Comment: Missing `)` and `}` in @DavidC.Rankin's comment.  `void *tmp = realloc(buffer, (strlen(buffer) + 2)); 
if (!tmp) { perror ("realloc-tmp"); break;} 
 buffer = tmp;`

Comment: Should be `void *tmp = realloc(buffer, strlen(buffer) + 2);` (too many `'('`)

Comment: @cdarke yes I figured, but still the same result :/ buffer variable still being affected by the printf and the perror string...

Comment: That is solely due to `buffer` not being initialized after being allocated. Either make it the empty-string (e.g. `*buffer = 0;` following `malloc`), or use `calloc` instead to set the new memory all zero.

Answer (score 4):

Sebastian, if you are still having problems after [@PaulOgilvie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3100312/paul-ogilvie) answer, then it is most likely due to not understanding his answer. Your problem is due to `buffer` being **allocated** but **not initialized**. When you call `malloc`, it allocates a block of at least the size requested, and returns a pointer to the beginning address for the new block -- *but does nothing with the contents of the new block*  -- meaning the block is full random values that just happened to be in the range of addresses for the new block.

So when you call `strcat(buffer, current_char_str);` the first time and there is nothing but random garbage in `buffer` and no *nul-terminating* character -- you do invoke *Undefined Behavior*. (there is no end-of-string in `buffer` to be found)

To fix the error, you simply need to make `buffer` an *empty-string* after it is allocated by setting the first character to the *nul-terminating* character, or use `calloc` instead to allocate the block which will ensure all bytes are set to zero.

For example:

```
int parse_path (const char *pathname)
{
    int char_index = 0, ccs_index = 0;
    char current_char = pathname[char_index];
    char *buffer = NULL;
    char *current_char_str = NULL;

    if (!(buffer = malloc (2))) {
        perror ("malloc-buffer");
        return 0;
    }
    *buffer = 0;    /* make buffer empty-string, or use calloc */
    ...
```

Also do not hardcode paths or numbers (that includes the `0` and `2`, but we will let those slide for now). Hardcoding `"this/is/a/path/hello"` within `parse_path()` make is a rather un-useful function. Instead, make your `pathname` variable your parameter so I can take any path you want to send to it...

While the whole idea of `realloc`'ing 2-characters at a time is rather inefficient, you always need to `realloc` with a temporary pointer rather than the pointer itself. Why? `realloc` can and does fail and when it does, it returns `NULL`. If you are using the pointer itself, you will overwrite your current pointer address with `NULL` in the event of failure, losing the address to your existing block of memory forever creating a memory leak. Instead,

```
            void *tmp = realloc (buffer, strlen(buffer) + 2);
            if (!tmp) {
                perror ("realloc-tmp");
                goto alldone;           /* use goto to break nested loops */
            }
            ...
    }
    alldone:;

    /* return something meaningful, your function is type 'int' */
}
```

A short example incorporating the fixes and temporary pointer would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int parse_path (const char *pathname)
{
    int char_index = 0, ccs_index = 0;
    char current_char = pathname[char_index];
    char *buffer = NULL;
    char *current_char_str = NULL;

    if (!(buffer = malloc (2))) {
        perror ("malloc-buffer");
        return 0;
    }
    *buffer = 0;    /* make buffer empty-string, or use calloc */

    if (!(current_char_str = malloc (2))) {
        perror ("malloc-current_char_str");
        return 0;
    }

    while (current_char != '\0' && (int) current_char != 11) {
        if (char_index == 0 && current_char == '/') {
            char_index++;
            current_char = pathname[char_index];
            continue;
        }

        while (current_char != '/' && current_char != '\0') {
            current_char_str[0] = current_char;
            current_char_str[1] = '\0';

            void *tmp = realloc (buffer, strlen(buffer) + 2);
            if (!tmp) {
                perror ("realloc-tmp");
                goto alldone;
            }
            strcat(buffer, current_char_str);

            char_index++;
            current_char = pathname[char_index];
        }

        if (strlen(buffer)) {
            printf("buffer(%s)\n", buffer);
            current_char_str[0] = '\0';
            buffer[0] = '\0';
        }

        if (current_char != '\0') {
            char_index++;
            current_char = pathname[char_index];
        }
    }
    alldone:;

    return ccs_index;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    parse_path ("this/is/a/path/hello");
    printf ("hello\n");

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** your logic is quite tortured above and you could just use a fixed buffer of `PATH_MAX` size (include `limits.h`) and dispense with allocating. Otherwise, you should allocate some anticipated number of characters for `buffer` to begin with, like `strlen (pathname)` which would ensure sufficient space for each path component without reallocating. I'd rather over-allocate by 1000-characters than screw up indexing worrying about reallocating 2-characters at a time...)

**Example Use/Output**

```
> bin\parsepath.exe
buffer(this)
buffer(is)
buffer(a)
buffer(path)
buffer(hello)
hello
```

**A More Straight-Forward Approach Without Allocation**

Simply using a buffer of `PATH_MAX` size or an allocated buffer of at least `strlen (pathname)` size will allow you to simply step down your string without any reallocations, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>  /* for PATH_MAX - but VS doesn't provide it, so we check */

#ifndef PATH_MAX
#define PATH_MAX  2048
#endif

void parse_path (const char *pathname)
{
    const char *p = pathname;
    char buffer[PATH_MAX], *b = buffer;

    while (*p) {
        if (*p == '/') {
            if (p != pathname) {
                *b = 0;
                printf ("buffer (%s)\n", buffer);
                b = buffer;
            }
        }
        else
            *b++ = *p;
        p++;
    }
    if (b != buffer) {
        *b = 0;
        printf ("buffer (%s)\n", buffer);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char *path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "this/is/a/path/hello";
    parse_path (path);
    printf ("hello\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
> parsepath2.exe
buffer (this)
buffer (is)
buffer (a)
buffer (path)
buffer (hello)
hello
```

Or

```
> parsepath2.exe another/path/that/ends/in/a/filename
buffer (another)
buffer (path)
buffer (that)
buffer (ends)
buffer (in)
buffer (a)
buffer (filename)
hello
```

Now you can pass any path you would like to parse as *an argument* to your program and it will be parsed without having to change or recompile anything. Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Deserves more than just +1. :)

Comment: Just glad to help. You could tell there was still a bit of confusion that needed to be removed. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: That is a very extensive answer!

Comment: You lead the horse to water, but for some reason he wouldn't drink. So I just took the water to him and poured it over his head `:)` Dunno if he actually drank, but he sure got wet...

Comment: Thank you very much for your descriptive answer.... the funny thing is though, even if I run your code that supposedly is a "fix", I still get the same problem where the printf is writing to the buffer variable.

Can there be something wrong with my compiler or something? I am using `gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)`

Comment: @SebastianKarlsson - that's not possible unless there is a character-set issue. You say you are using `gcc 6.3.0`, but on what? Is it in WSL, or is this a MinGW install. The only thing I can think of is you have either captured a carriage-return in the text you are using as input, you are using UTF-8 (or UTF-16) character set, or something in that manner. Copy and paste my code into an editor and make sure you are saving with `'\n'` line endings. Then compile `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -Ofast -o parsepath parsepath.c` (that's `'Oh fast'` not zero) and try again. (either version)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin still the same problem even if I compile with your compile optionss :/ I am saving your code in ViM on a Linux machine so it should not be a problem

Comment: What is your current setup? What operating system, what compiler, etc..? I have compiled and run both on Linux and Windows using gcc and VS and no issues (even compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` on gcc and with `/W3` on VS). That's why I say there is a character set problem somewhere. Are you sure the double-quotes you are using are not actually web-left/right non-ASCII quotes? It is going to be a subtle problem like that.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am running Debian 9 on a Dell XPS 13.... yes the file is saved in correct format! Now this is weird, I got it working by adding changing the condition in the outer while loop to: `c != '\0' && char_index < strlen(pathname)` . So for some reason the buffer variable is filled with other data ... even if it should not since we did `*buffer = 0;` ... this is really strange.

Comment: @SebastianKarlsson - I found the issue, you needed one more test `if (current_char != '\0')` at the end of your main loop before advancing `char_index++;` once again which could advance it past the *nul-terminator` if already set to that at the end of the prior loop (another reason why avoiding multiple nested loops is a good idea)

Answer (score 2):

You `strcat` something to `buffer` but `buffer` has never been initialized. `strcat` will first search for the first null character and then copy the string to concatenate there. You are now probably overwriting memory that is not yours.

Before the outer `while` loop do:

```
    *buffer= '\0';
```

Comment: Still the same result even if I do this

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main problems in your code:

- the arrays allocated by `malloc()` are not initialized, so you have undefined behavior when you call `strlen(buffer)` before setting a null terminator inside the array `buffer` points to. The program could just crash, but in your case whatever contents is present in the memory block and after it is retained up to the first null byte.
- just before the end of the outer loop, you should only take the next character from the path if the current character is a `'/'`. In your case, you skip the null terminator and the program has undefined behavior as you read beyond the end of the string constant. Indeed, the parse continues through another string constant `"buffer(%s)\n"` and through yet another one `"hello"`. The string constants seem to be adjacent without padding on your system, which is just a coincidence.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void parse_path(const char *pathname) {
    int char_index = 0;
    char current_char = pathname[char_index];
    char *buffer = calloc(1, 1);
    char *current_char_str = calloc(1, 1);

    while (current_char != '\0' && current_char != 11) {
        if (char_index == 0 && current_char == '/') {
            char_index++; current_char = pathname[char_index];
            continue;
        }
        while (current_char != '/' && current_char != '\0') {
            current_char_str[0] = current_char;
            current_char_str[1] = '\0';

            buffer = (char *)realloc(buffer, strlen(buffer) + 2);
            strcat(buffer, current_char_str);

            char_index++; current_char = pathname[char_index];
        }
        if (strlen(buffer)) {
            printf("buffer(%s)\n", buffer);
            current_char_str[0] = '\0';
            buffer[0] = '\0';
        }
        if (current_char == '/') {
            char_index++; current_char = pathname[char_index];
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    parse_path("this/is/a/path/hello");
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
buffer(this)
buffer(is)
buffer(a)
buffer(path)
buffer(hello)
hello
```

Note however some remaining problems:

- allocation failure is not tested, resulting in undefined behavior,
- allocated blocks are not freed, resulting in memory leaks,
- it is unclear why you test `current_char != 11`:  did you mean to stop at TAB or newline?

Here is a much simpler version with the same behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void parse_path(const char *pathname) {
    int i, n;

    for (i = 0; pathname[i] != '\0'; i += n) {
        if (pathname[i] == '/') {
            n = 1;  /* skip path separators and empty items */
        } else {
            n = strcspn(pathname + i, "/");  /* get the length of the path item */
            printf("buffer(%.*s)\n", n, pathname + i);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    parse_path("this/is/a/path/hello");
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```