# My program doesn't work with strcat - I can't seem to get why?

Tags: c++

As a homework, I have to make a program which replaces all the words made of 3 letters with a "*".

For example:

```
input: cod is everything and I love it
output: * is everything * I love it
```

Here is my program:

```
int main()
{
    char cuvant[101], final[101];
    char* pch;
    cin.get(cuvant, 100);
    pch = strtok(cuvant, " ");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        if (strlen(pch) == 3)
        {
            strcat(final, " *");
        }
        else
        {
            strcat(final, " ");
            strcat(final, pch);
        }
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    cout << final;
}
```

I don't get any error - but the output is blank. Also, the program doesn't exit with the code 0 (as it should be), it says "exited with code -1073741819". So obviously something is going on.

Am I using strtok/strcat wrong?

I feel like strcat can't be used in my case and this is the reason for the error, but I'm not sure. Am I right?

If so, how can I solve my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Use `std::string`
2. Use `+` to concatenate

Comment: It would be a good start to ensure *valid* strings at the start (final is in an undefined state). Also, since C++, "just" stringstream?

Comment: Please choose between C and C++. I wish StackOverflow wouldn't let you select both.

Comment: @AndyG I'm sorry - the reason I do that is because in class we are studying c++, but actually we are doing a lot of c-style things. Including using arrays of chars. I can't use std::string unfortunately.

Comment: @user2864740 how can they not be valid?

Comment: @JohnSmith The arguments go like this: on assignments requiring things done in C-ways, use *only* C. On assignments using/teaching C++, use C++.

Comment: `strcat` requires the destination to be a null-terminated char array. `char final[101]` declares an uninitialized array, so your call to `strcat` invokes undefined behavior

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do i first have to strcpy() before strcat()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838933/why-do-i-first-have-to-strcpy-before-strcat)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's not about money - this is how things are in my country. I'm in high school, and this is what we study.

Comment: Use **`return 0;`**  at the end of the code , to remove Error   :  **program doesn't exit with the code 0**

Comment: @UnholySheep alright, this is by far the most useful answer. How can I solve my problem though?

Comment: @RaymondChen I'll look into it right now. Thanks.

Comment: Just a rather stupid remark about C/C++. I know they are different languages and lead to different codes. But it is still still common to give beginners some knowledge on both. I have often mixed C and C++ in the same program: each compilation unit using a single language but some being C and others C++. Rationales: legacy library or code usage, or very low level (hardware) programming where C is more appropriate, and C++ for the higher level constructs. But anyway mixing both libraries in same translation unit is indeed allowed per C++ but should be avoided if possible...

Comment: When you see a program return a huge (or hugely negative) number like -1073741819, usually its the computer trying to tell you something. Convert it into hex (0xC0000005) to see if the code is more recognizable. Here is a list of [Magic Debug Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values) that often, but not this time, help.

Comment: @SayedM.Idrees that's not required for C++ and C99 (or newer). In `int main` the `return 0;` is implicit. A non-0 return indicates that something else caused the program to terminate abnormally

Comment: @SayedM.Idrees the program dies horribly long before it reaches a `return`. This code was automatically returned when the program crashed trying to access memory it did not own.

Comment: @user4581301 great answer. I knew that a code different than 0 means there's something wrong - but I didn't know that i need to conver it to hex. I just tried to search it online.

Comment: You're welcome. You don't always need to convert it to hex. It's just something to try when you don't recognize what a number means.

Comment: @JohnSmith -- I know that you're not allowed to use C++, but [see this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a9f05f3ccc161a9) as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `final`

```
strcpy(final, "");
```

to make it null terminated before you start using it with strcat.

or just set

```
final[0] = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that all the `C-String` functions expect your string to be null terminated (ie the character `'\0'` as the last character of a string.

The problem is that `final` is not initialized. It can contain any amount of raw garbage. So when you use `strcat()` it has to find the end (which could be anywhere).

The solution is to initialize `final` to make sure it is a zero length `C-String`.

```
 char cuvant[101];
 char final[101]  ={0}; // Fills the array with zero
```

Or.

```
 char final[101];
 final[0] = '\0'; // Make a C-String of length 0
```

---

Return code.

In C++ the return code is 0. But in C it is undefined (as you have no return statement). So you compiled your code with the C compiler not the C++ compiler.

An undefined value can be anything. The value `-1073741819` is valid as anything.

Comment: Great answer as well. This is the solution - but the other answer was faster so I will accept that one. Thanks for your time though!

Answer (score 1):

try this for 'c'

```
memset( cuvant, 0, sizeof( cuvant )); 
memset( final, 0, sizeof( final ));
```

Comment: What is memset doing?

Comment: memset() sets the block of memory to the value specified...  in the above it sets all the elements to 0, therefore initializing the memory to zero.

Answer (score 1):

C++'s string extractors split input on whitespace; that can save you a bunch of parsing.

```
std::string word;
std::string result;
while (std::cin >> word) {
    result += ' ';
    if (word.length == 3)
        result += '*';
    else
        result += word;
```

Comment: I can't use std::string in my problems unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

you can make the if statement looks like this :

```
if (strlen(pch) == 3)
    {
        strcat(final, "* ");
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(final, pch);
        strcat(final, " ");
    }
```

so the **final** string will not start by termination char.

Comment: Would this help my problem?

Comment: yes, you got a blank output cuz you start the string with null terminator, but in my suggestions, you will make sure that it's start with a valid char.